# Upgrade iPhone 4G from iOS 4.1 to any iOS

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

Is there any possibility for me to upgrade to any iOS on my iPhone 4G from iOS 4.1?

Mine is still a nice stable phone, but I can't download any apps. It is jailbroken, unlocked and I have saved the SHSH blobs if that would help.

I have tried updating for a long time, but it did not work because the Apple signing has ceased by the time I try.

Comment: Last iOS for the 4G was iOS 7.1.2. Apple are still signing that for any device that cannot update further.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to plug your iPhone into a computer and update using iTunes to the latest iOS version. This will of course undo the jailbreak.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade iPhone 4G to latest iOS 7.1.2, but since your iPhone is jailbreak, the phone itself cannot complete the upgrade. You need connect the phone with itunes on computer, and use iTunes to complete the upgrade process.